# How to Find Html Element in Back-end Code in C# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find **lbl01** Lable ID in Code Behind

My html is this

```
<table id="customers">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Box</th>
        <th>Box2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <td>
            <label id="lbl01">some text</label></td>
        <td>
            <label id="lbl02">some text</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code is

```
var L1 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl(ContIDL1);
var L2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl(ContIDL2);
```

but L1 and L2 is **null**

any help

Comment: What's `ContIDL1`? In general, you can't access HTML controls if they are not `runat=server`

Comment: i want to generate that lable dynamically that why i want this without runat server attribute

Comment: You can generate it dynamically with `runat=server` as server-control. But i'd prefer a databound server control like a `GridView` which is rendered as a table